# Infer parameters of function according to key of other object property

Tags: typescript

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/ATDGHsDsGcBdgIYAcnALyIO4IJb1AE4CmCsRAgigBQDeAsAFAggC24AJgK4A2R0AXMHpNmIdqQSDho0QDMEoWOAIBPQVQCU6AHzAACgXAsc0IgDpi0cNwBuRKpp3BajGTNMEbOUHymu3MoQkZABKfOCcBD7qWmi6NAC+-gHASSJuCRoaycwJADQ5IJweAkKFzOxESKUA2gDk4rAIZkGkRGFWkT51ALoF6TLyispqzrG6BkYm5pbWdg6toeFdRDFONuA47OPOiVl5wAD0h8AAPAC058DQABYR3OzAkODwRASGBMA3b0Tl+eXFN7QABMfgGokq1UE9UazUW7WWUSIvX6KSGSlUazi+kMxlMFnCtnsjmxtEyGgOxzOl2udx4jzeHy+P2ceOgOEgAHMwMQ2h0IkjgJCiJBKpBQCpsuDUqiZICCNAAMxglKQ2p1UAKb4o8ogdEjLETXHTAlWIkOHZk-ZHE4XK63e4M97KZnEVkmdlcsBaohCqoisUSqUZWWieXQAAsKoCauhGp9dQODQkLV5S06SJ10r1CgxoxJRqm+Nm5oLu3JlNtNId9OAjJd3zdVDZHO5mtA30Qop5wQRGZ8fqQAZFoBwfGDMn+0vDAFZo25Y8B6u3tUnYane-yVlm0bmDWMnJM8TNCfMqCvVgfsRstgd4VukYbgDftk4rRSbdT7XSHk8XnXnU+RtfmlKdRDA5gPC8HxSmkQIfSkYB9UxK9C2PU05mJS09i0CCQAgzIAG5GEYWAVCHYAAFkOB4BFYEiSB0DKEQoO8PgAH5BDCCACHYU44AIVsDgQSAVG0RgEmIhhSPI31qK4XgADE91UU4ABEqmgOsAA8yFFLSRJUGoeiYwzjN0DAyyPaZTioMx7IQAhOVKDTqh2eTaLCeiCEgbQpLIiiAGU3mgohlOGVTXK0ohdIDAzROM0yEp6CzUJxIsiFs+yzEc5zBCinZDL8kiGAC30AFFdIIXMPN4YLPDYgBpIgVGgU4ABUdL09gtNqsKVLEpiAGsWvAWRgC8hj2tk05-HIbA8CIPjJp86ahw67RxIYbR6lYmDemAAAyfwBNbKTGBipBlHgBBoBUcUkM4cVYBwKAezaSgkFmkROpi7qtLg1gaN4UpuOUPjTq5A5AYqTTON2YBdSXRrgA5ZwRpUMbgHa+o2AUvheg0HpBAAAwAEhoFHDuuWBBK5BIzApyraZq4GiHq0LmtajrcbZ6BehqRqehqAAiZCVBFlKEhJv4agxrGcbqPHaP5noTIAH2AeXxsVvaCZ6DRjNDZgRQQAAjXh2Hhqg4DaQRDJ2M3wGsEhICktxxcEPrwrzWztex3aQrY1XDZSnIEm0Y29dg8oakC1HGP93Wg-2tX5xkNVrcq0BuE4SpTiTwOGtTg5Au0UPjbkAbBA5tifZGP3Rp1ovQpD8y-nD2U0m0c8oFkHBOUEdqtESIA)

I'm trying to build a DI framework, and I have two sibling objects (`modules` and `services`), which can reference themselves by key. Each can provide a `factory` into which the relevant service (either a global `service` or a service provided by a `module`, e.g. `data.createResource`) is passed.

I have the correct inference for the string value of the deps, but I can't work out how to ensure that the dependencies are inferred from those keys.

Edit: I should also say that the `deps` array describes the factory parameters in the order in which they are provided, i.e:

```
deps: ['cache', 'data.createResource'],
factory: () => Promise.resolve((cache, createResource) => {}),
```

```
  const app = await createApp({
    modules: {
      data: {
        factory: () => Promise.resolve(() => ({
          services: {
            createResource: () => {}
          }
        }))
      },
      users: {
        deps: ['data.createResource'],
        factory: () => Promise.resolve((createResource: () => void) => ({})), // <-- should not error here
      },
      users2: {
        deps: ['data.createResource'],
        factory: () => Promise.resolve(() => ({})), // <-- should error here (missing createResource dependency)
      },
      users3: {
        deps: ['cache'],
        factory: () => Promise.resolve(() => ({})), // <-- should error here (missing cache dependency)
      },
      users4: {
        deps: ['cache', 'data.createResource'],
        factory: () => Promise.resolve(() => ({})), // <-- should error here (missing cache and createResource dependencies)
      },
      users5: {
        deps: ['cache', 'data.createResource'],
        factory: () => Promise.resolve((cache: () => void, createResource: () => void) => ({})), // <-- should not error here
      },
    },
    services: {
      cache: { factory: () => Promise.resolve(() => ({})) },
    },
  });

type ModuleReturn = {
  services?: Record<string, any>
};

type ModuleFactory<Deps extends any[] = any[]> = () => Promise<(...args: Deps) => ModuleReturn>;
type ServiceFactory<Deps extends any[] = any[]> = () => Promise<(...args: Deps) => any>;

type ExtractModuleServiceKeys<T extends ModuleFactory> = keyof ReturnType<
  Awaited<ReturnType<T>>
>['services'] &
  string;

export async function createApp<
  T extends {
    modules: Record<string, {
      deps?: ({ 
        [K in (keyof T['modules'])]: `${K & string}.${ExtractModuleServiceKeys<T['modules'][K]["factory"]>}`
      }[keyof T['modules']] | keyof T['services'])[],
      enabled?: (state: any) => boolean;
      factory: ModuleFactory<(keyof T['services'])[]>
    }>,
    services: {
      [S in keyof T['services']]: {
        deps?: (Exclude<keyof T['services'], S>)[],
        factory: ServiceFactory<(keyof T['services'])[]>
      }
    },
  }
>(config: T) {}
```

Comment: So, are the function arguments always callbacks without arguments and `void` return type?

Comment: No they're not - they should be inferred from the resolved `Promise`s of the factory definitions. They could be any shape. I just defined them like this for brevity.

Comment: Ok but the function `createResource` does not resolve to a `Promise`

Comment: That's correct. The required shape for both `services` and `modules` is that `factory` is a function that returns a `Promise`. 

The difference is that a `service`'s `Promise` can resolve to anything, but a `module`'s `Promise` must return a `service` property.

Essentially, we have "global" services, and services that are provided by a `module`. The only async requirement is on the `factory` return value.

Comment: So for `'data.createResource'`, it would just be the type of `createResource`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly correct.

Comment: What happens when a module references itself https://tsplay.dev/WvAaQm. Or what about circular dependencies??

Comment: And what happens, if there is a `key` called `cache` in both the `services` object **and** the `modules` object?

Comment: Circular references should be disallowd (I'm actually excluding them in the services definition but hadn't yet done it for modules).

Comment: Keys shouldn't be able to clash because module services are always prefixed with the module name, so `cache` and `someModule.cache` (or `cache.someService`.

Comment: The three errors you want to have are not possible. TypeScript does not force implementers of functions to declare all arguments. See [this Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAYgOxgXhgCgIYCcDmAuGAZxCwEsEcBKFAPhgDcB7UgE2GAGNGFiYAzBAEYCiFOmz4iJclVowA3gF9O3XgIBMIpKjTVkdJcCA)

Comment: Ah of course, thanks for your help today.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that this is not possible. It is possible to create a relation between the `deps` and `factory` properties in each object, but this collides with the other rules about the allowed strings. Also the fact that `deps` is optional is a problem because it breaks proper inference in some places.